# Ruby convention for accessing first/last element in array

Tags: ruby, coding-style

This is a question about conventions. The two sets of commands below return identical results.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

a.first  # => 1
a[0]     # => 1

a.last   # => 3
a[-1]    # => 3
```

Which of these is preferred in Ruby, the explicit index or the functions? Assuming, of course, that this is in code which *always* accesses the first or last element.

Note: I've been thinking about the cycles each would take. Because `first` and `last` accept parameters, they will have a little more overhead, but I don't know if that affects what the community prefers.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

If you read the comments on this post, there was a big debate about my last paragraph. While I failed to remember that `[x]` is equivalent to `.[](x)`, I was correct in my conclusion that first and last have a bit more overhead. Considering the nature of both, I believe that this is due to the argument check for `first`/`last`. These need to check if there are arguments whereas `[]` can assume that they exist.

**CODE**

```
require 'benchmark'

a = [1..1000]

MAX = 1000000

Benchmark.bm(15) do |b|
  b.report("small first") { MAX.times do; a.first; end }
  b.report("small [0]")   { MAX.times do; a[0];    end }
  b.report("small last")  { MAX.times do; a.last;  end }
  b.report("small [-1]")  { MAX.times do; a[-1];   end }
end

a = [1..100000000000]

Benchmark.bm(15) do |b|
  b.report("large first") { MAX.times do; a.first; end }
  b.report("large [0]")   { MAX.times do; a[0];    end }
  b.report("large last")  { MAX.times do; a.last;  end }
  b.report("large [-1]")  { MAX.times do; a[-1];   end }
end
```

**RESULTS**

```
                      user     system      total        real
small first       0.350000   0.000000   0.350000 (  0.901497)
small [0]         0.330000   0.010000   0.340000 (  0.857786)
small last        0.370000   0.000000   0.370000 (  1.054216)
small [-1]        0.370000   0.000000   0.370000 (  1.137655)
                      user     system      total        real
large first       0.340000   0.010000   0.350000 (  0.897581)
large [0]         0.320000   0.010000   0.330000 (  0.889725)
large last        0.350000   0.000000   0.350000 (  1.071135)
large [-1]        0.380000   0.000000   0.380000 (  1.119587)
```

Comment: I believe it is .first and .last because it makes it easier to ready and ruby is a language that is meant to be read. Also it makes it easier for people to glance through your code and know what you are doing

Comment: This is probably a matter of opinion more than "what's best", but I would prefer `first` and `last` if that's exactly what I meant. If you're really concerned about real time performance, Ruby's probably not your best choice of scripting languages. ;)

Comment: We use `first` and `last` because they're available. They're available because they're needed a lot more often. Other accessors to array positions are available in Rails, but they're really not that useful or readable and, though people could use them, we see `[n]` notation more often. It's not really that much harder to read `[n]`, and it's infinitely more practical as they're easy to use in loops.

Comment: From [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#collections): *When accessing the first or last element from an array, prefer `first` or `last` over `[0]` or `[-1]`.*

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. `[]` accept parameters as well.

Comment: @sawa `[1, 2, 3].first(2) # => [1, 2]`

Comment: I thought you were mentioning `[0]` and `[-1]` only. Besides that, I don't understand how that matches with your last paragraph. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It was a just a note as to why `first` and `last` might have a little more overhead.

Comment: As I wrote, `[]` accept arguments as well. Why do `first` and `last` might have overhead compared to `[]`?

Comment: @screenmutt Whereas `first` is a method that takes a parameter, `[]` is also a method that takes a parameter (with `[1]`, it is actually `.[](1)`. So, technically, any overhead that `.first` has, `[]` also has.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell Hadn't thought of that. I'm still a little bit stuck in non-Ruby world. I'm going to run some tests on these two.

Comment: @screenmutt Whether `[]` is a method taking an argument or not is not something you "think of". It is something you know or not know. And I was mentioning about your logic, not about the real speed. This is independent of tests.

Comment: @sawa You're wrong there. I do "know" that everything in Ruby is a method, however I didn't "think" of it when I was considering this problem.

Comment: @sawa Which is what I said in the comment...

Comment: Don't your "RESULTS" show the opposite? [-1] being actually slower?

Comment: @silverdr I believe the main comparison is between first and [0]. But I wouldn't trust any of these results given they are 7 years old.

Comment: @DanGrahn - I see. I re-ran the snippet and even on 2.2.6 it shows both `first` and `last` being slower than the indexed counterparts. The same on 2.5.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Code is read more than it is written**, and `first` and `last` take less effort to understand, especially for a less experienced Ruby programmer or someone from a language with different indexing semantics.

While most programmers will immediately know that these are the same:

```
a.first
a[0]
```

the first still reads more easily. There isn't a marked difference in how hard it is to read, but it's there.

`last` is another issue. Accessing the index 0 will get you the first element of an array in almost any language. But negative indexing is only available in some languages. If a C programmer with minimal Ruby experience is trying to read my code, which will they understand faster?:

```
a.last
a[-1]
```

The negative index will probably force them to do a Google search.

Comment: I had faced the same when I started Ruby with the style `a[-1]`...  :) :)

Comment: @Babai: So did I. That's why it's good for its more powerful uses (eg. `a[0..-1]`) but not for just getting the last element.

Comment: A C programmer would also grimace and think "Oh my gosh, they are reading random data!" (data at address of a - sizeof(a)).

Comment: Downvoter? Explaination?

Comment: @JamesR. Yep. It's not intuitive notation.

Answer (score 2):

Since Matz designed Ruby after a few other languages, I think the conventions come from those other languages.

In Lisp, one of Ruby's inspirational parents, you would use something close to the `last` and `first` methods so I'll say `last` and `first` is convention.

I only really use `first` and `last`. I see many programs out there that use those methods but ultimately it is your choice. That's the beauty of Ruby ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the point of view of the speed, for larger arrays, `first` and `last` are faster than `[]`. For smaller arrays it is the other way around.

Large array:

```
array = (0..100000000).to_a

t = Time.now
10.times{array[0]}
puts Time.now - t
# => 0.000225356

t = Time.now
10.times{array.first}
puts Time.now - t
# => 2.9736e-05

t = Time.now
10.times{array[-1]}
puts Time.now - t
# => 7.847e-06

t = Time.now
10.times{array.last}
puts Time.now - t
# => 6.174e-06
```

Small array:

```
array = (0..100).to_a

t = Time.now
10.times{array[0]}
puts Time.now - t
# => 4.403e-06

t = Time.now
10.times{array.first}
puts Time.now - t
# => 5.933e-06

t = Time.now
10.times{array[-1]}
puts Time.now - t
# => 4.982e-06

t = Time.now
10.times{array.last}
puts Time.now - t
# => 5.411e-06
```

For ease of writing/reading, `first` and `last` can be used without arguments, unlike `[]`, so they are simpler.

Sometimes, using `first` and `last` makes things easier, while it is difficult with `[]`: e.g., `array.each_slice(3).map(&:first)`.

Comment: Please provide tests to verify `first` and `last` are faster. Intuitively, I would think they would be slower.

Comment: Can we see benchmarks? I'm curious ;)

Comment: I just added benchmarks to my question.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but @Linuxios had a better answer because it contained more focus and explanation of why convention is easier. Props for doing the testing. BTW `benchmark` is the best package in ruby!

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the standard, but its syntax is little too complicated for me. It just doesn't come to mind immediately how to use it when I want to.