# Regex for First Line (Only) that Contains a String

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a bunch of phone numbers with one per line:

```
[Home] (202) 121-7777 
C (202) 456-1111
[mobile] 55 55 5 55555 
[Work] (404) 555-1234 
[Cell] (505) 555-1234
W 303-555-5555
M 777-555-5555
c 12346567s
```

I want to grab the **first one** that contains the letter "c" upper or lower case.

So far, I have this `/^.*[C].*$/i` and that matches `C (202) 456-1111`, `[Cell] (505) 555-1234` and `c 12346567s`. How do I return only the first? In other words, the match should only be `C (202) 456-1111`.

I have been blindly putting [question marks everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519572/return-first-match-of-ruby-regex) without success.

I am using Ruby if it makes a difference http://www.rubular.com/r/h6ReB9IN8t

Edit: Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match) that Hrishi pointed to but I cannot figure out how to adapt it to match the whole line.

Comment: maybe you should look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519572/return-first-match-of-ruby-regex

Comment: Thanks. I saw that one too but I must be missing something obvious. I will add it to the references, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: is `[Cell] (505) 555-1234`  number your candidate solution ?? i mean it starts does not start with C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go about this a bit differently. I prefer to reduce regular expressions to very simple patterns:

```
str = <<EOT
[Home] (202) 121-7777
C (202) 456-1111
[mobile] 55 55 5 55555
[Work] (404) 555-1234
[Cell] (505) 555-1234
W 303-555-5555
M 777-555-5555
c 12346567s
EOT
```

Finding the right line to work with is easily done using either `select` or `find`:

```
str.split("\n").select{ |s| s[/c/i] }.first # => "C (202) 456-1111"
str.split("\n").find{ |s| s[/c/i] } # => "C (202) 456-1111"
```

I'd recommend `find` because it only returns the first occurrence.

Once the desired string is found, use `scan` to grab the numbers:

```
str.split("\n").find{ |s| s[/c/i] }.scan(/\d+/) # => ["202", "456", "1111"]
```

Then `join` them. When you have phone numbers stored in a database you don't really want them to be formatted, you just want the numbers. Formatting occurs later when you're outputting them again.

```
phone_number = str.split("\n").find{ |s| s[/c/i] }.scan(/\d+/).join # => "2024561111"
```

When you need to output the number, break it into the right grouping based on the regional phone-number representation. You should have some idea where the person is located, because you've usually also got their country code. Based on that you know how many digits you should have, plus the groups:

```
area_code, prefix, number = phone_number[0 .. 2], phone_number[3 .. 5], phone_number[6 .. 9] # => ["202", "456", "1111"]
```

Then output them so they're displayed correctly:

```
"(%s) %s-%s" % [area_code, prefix, number] # => "(202) 456-1111"
```

As far as your original pattern `/^.*[C].*$/i`, there are some things wrong with your understanding of regex:

- `^.*` says "start at the beginning of the string and find zero or more characters", which is no more effective than saying `/[C]`.
- Using `[C]` creates an unnecessary character-set which means "find one of the letters in the set "C"; It does nothing useful, so just use `C` as `/C`.
- `.*$` artificially finds the end of the string also, but since you're not capturing it there's nothing accomplished, so don't bother with it. The regex is now `/C/`.
- Since you want to match upper and lower-case, use `/C/i` or `/c/i`. (Or you could use `/[cC]/` but why?)

Instead:

- To find a "c" or "C" anywhere in the string, just use `/c/i`. That's all that's needed. http://rubular.com/r/uPyxACOWls
- To find "c", "C" or "cell" or "Cell", you can use `/c(?:ell)?/`. http://rubular.com/r/TkSRPWG2y6
- To find "c", "C", "cell" or "Cell" as a separate word, use word-break markers like `/\bc(?:ell)?\b/`. http://rubular.com/r/Smo0bFs9w8

You can get a whole lot more complicated, but if you're not accomplishing anything with the additional pattern information, you're just wasting the regex-engine's CPU-time, and slowing your code. A confused regex-engine can waste a LOT of CPU-time, so be efficient and aware of what you're asking it to do.

Comment: This provides the answer and instruction on improving the code. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Try `match` method. Here is an example:

```
list = <<EOF
[Home] (202) 121-7777 
C (202) 456-1111
[mobile] 55 55 5 55555 
[Work] (404) 555-1234 
[Cell] (505) 555-1234
W 303-555-5555
M 777-555-5555
c 12346567s
EOF
```

**Update**

```
#match line with "c" letter in line, even that are part of word
puts list.match(/^.*C.*$/i) 

#match line with "c" letter in line, that are not a part of word
puts list.match(/^\W*C\W.*$/i)
```

Comment: this does not even work :)
please have a look at :
http://www.rubular.com/r/h6ReB9IN8t

Comment: I tryed it in my rubby and it returns only first match. Regexp does match 3 instances, but match method returns only first.

Comment: this also matches [Cell] (505) 555-1234 , i am not very sure if the question is considering this as a valid input. If yes your solution is correct and i will upvote you :)

Comment: If you want to match only "c" letters, that are not in word you can try this regexp: http://www.rubular.com/r/O7YdvZhCXR

Comment: `/^\W*C\W.*$/i` will be better, than my previous regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string by  the new line characters, and `select` the substring which matches your requirements and grab the first one:

```
str = '[Home] (202) 121-7777 
C (202) 456-1111
[mobile] 55 55 5 55555 
[Work] (404) 555-1234 
[Cell] (505) 555-1234
W 303-555-5555
M 777-555-5555
c 12346567s'

p str.split(/\n/).select{|el| el =~ /^.*[C].*$/i}[0]
```

or use `match`:

```
p str.match(/^.*[C].*$/i)[0]
```

---

EDITED:

Or, in case you want to find the first chunk that exactly starts with `C` try this:

```
p str.match(/^C.*$/)[0]
```

Comment: this also matches `[Cell] (505) 555-1234` , i am not very sure if the question is considering this as a valid input. If yes your solution is correct and i will upvote you :)

Comment: FYI, `[0]` is not preferred ruby syntax. You should be using `.first`

Comment: str.match(/^.*[C].*$/i)[0] works. I was hoping for a purely regular expression answer but this gets the job done in one step, without an additional loop.

Comment: @sahildhankhar , did you run the code? Both parts return `C (202) 456-1111` ;)

Comment: @screenmutt , could you provide reference to `preferred` syntax, please?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev [Top Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) and [Ruby convention for accessing first and last array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212240/ruby-convention-for-accessing-first-last-element-in-array).

Comment: @screenmutt , there are just opinions and styles. I didn't see any reasonable arguments. I could have my own style as long as I don't violate syntax http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev It's about readability. `first` is preferred because it is easier to read than `[0]`. When posting code to SO, you should follow language standards. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18212600/1669208).

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev it depends if the input is str = '[Cell] (505) 555-1234[Home] (202) 121-7777 
C (202) 456-1111
[mobile] 55 55 5 55555 
[Work] (404) 555-1234 
W 303-555-5555
M 777-555-5555
c 12346567s'

the output will be different and yes i did run the code :)

Comment: I can only quote the reason why this topic was closed: `Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.`

Comment: @sahildhankhar , I understood this question as `find the first occurence with C, c or [C in any case`...

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev yes make sense, i guess this is what the asker wants. you have my upvote now :)

Comment: @sahildhankhar , I'm not so sure. Here could be a scenario where record has a lot of phones and I need to find first cell phone. And each cell phone could be coded in different way: C , c or [Cell]. So...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Added two more ways of handling this. The last one is preferable.

This will do what you want. It will search for matches of your regex, and then get the first one. Please note that this will produce an error if string does not have any matches.

```
string = "[Home] (202) 121-7777 
C (202) 456-1111
[mobile] 55 55 5 55555 
[Work] (404) 555-1234 
[Cell] (505) 555-1234
W 303-555-5555
M 777-555-5555
c 12346567s"

puts string.match(/^(.*[C].*)$/i).captures.first
puts string.match(/^(.*[C].*)$/i)
puts string[/^(.*[C].*)$/i]
```

[Ruby Docs `String#match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-match).